# Using Visual Studio 2010 Express C#, how to debug a C# DLL used by some third party C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

I would like to debug a C# DLL I'm developing for a plugin that is used by some third-party production .EXE for which I do not have the code.

How should I configure the Visual Studio 2010 Express C# solution so that I can set breakpoints that are honoured by Visual Studio when I execute the third-party .EXE that loads my DLL?

Comment: Debug->Attach to process

Comment: Go to `Debug` menu and choose `Attach To Process`.  Select the third party tool process and click ok.  Your break point should get hit.

Comment: In some cases, most reasonable way is to use `Debugger.Break()` and then attach a debugger

Comment: @DrKoch Is attaching a debugger available for Visual Studio 2010 Express C#?  I do not see this menu item in my VS 201 C# and I do not see VS 2010 either listed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx

Comment: Probably you need a more complete Version of Visual Studio to do this. It is the way to go.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The link above is a completely different question